# For random variable $Z=\max_i X_i$, can we bound $\mathbb{E}(Z|Z>\tau)$ with $\mathbb{E}(Z)$

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation, tail-bound

Let $X_1,…,X_n$ be independent, but not necessarily identical, *non-negative* random variables. Let $Z=\max_i(X_i)$. Fix a real $\tau > 0$. Is there a way to lower bound $$\mathbb{E}(Z|Z>\tau) > c \mathbb{E}(Z)$$ for constant $c>1$ (that can obviously depend on $\tau$). For example if $\tau$ is the median of $Z$ or $\mathbb{E}(Z)/2$

Comment: Not in the $\tau = \mathbb{E}(Z)/2$ case since you might for example have the $X_i$ supported on $[6,10]$ so $\mathbb{E}(Z)/2 \le 5$ and $\mathbb{E}(Z\mid Z>\tau) =1 \times \mathbb{E}(Z)$.  I am not sure what the $X_i$ contribute here rather than just looking at $Z$

Comment: @Henry $X_i$ just here to restrict valid $Z$ variables (as max of non negative random variables) and also in case there is a lower bound in terms of mean/variance of the individual $X_i$ instead.

Comment: In the median case I think you can say $\mathbb{E}(Z\mid Z>\tau)\ge \max(\tau,2\mathbb{E}(Z) -\tau)$

Comment: @Henry can you sketch the proof for the median inequality? (Or in general the p-th percentile if you can generalize)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Requested in comments:*

Clearly in general  $\mathbb{E}[Z\mid Z\le \tau] \le \tau \lt \mathbb{E}[Z\mid Z>\tau]$,  assuming the expectations exist.

If $\tau$ is the median of $Z$ then:

- $\mathbb P(Z>\tau) \le \frac12 \le \mathbb P(Z\le \tau)$
- $\mathbb{E}[Z] =  \mathbb P(Z>\tau)\,\mathbb{E}[Z\mid Z>\tau] + \mathbb P(Z\le\tau)\,\mathbb{E}[Z\mid Z\le\tau]$
- so $\mathbb{E}[Z] \le \frac12  \mathbb{E}[Z\mid Z>\tau] + \frac12  \mathbb{E}[Z\mid Z\le\tau] $
- and thus  $\mathbb{E}[Z] \le \frac12  \mathbb{E}[Z\mid Z>\tau]+ \frac12 \tau $
- implying $\mathbb{E}[Z\mid Z>\tau] \ge 2 \mathbb{E}[Z] -\tau$
- which combined with the earlier result gives $$\mathbb{E}(Z\mid Z>\tau)\ge \max(\tau,2\mathbb{E}(Z) -\tau).$$

If you extended this to the $p$th quantile of $Z$ so $\mathbb P(Z\le \tau) \ge  p$ and  $\mathbb P(Z>\tau)\le 1-p$ then the same argument would give you  $\mathbb{E}[Z\mid Z>\tau] \ge \max\left(\tau,\frac{\mathbb{E}[Z]-p\tau}{1-p}\right). $